# How to place two SilverStripe DefinedUserForms in home page

Tags: php, silverstripe

In SilverStripe how do you display two `UserDefinedForm`s on one page?

I can display one `UserDefinedForm` on a page, but I am unable to display two on the same page. I would like to display two `UserDefinedForm`s on my home page.

To display one `UserDefinedForm` I put this in my `HomePage` template:

```
<div id="contactForm" style="display: none;">
<% control ShowForm %>
    <p><strong>$SiteConfig.FormHeading</strong></p>
    $Form
<% end_control %>
</div>
```

Function `ShowForm()` is in my `HomePage.php`

```
function ShowForm() {
    $get = DataObject::get_one('UserDefinedForm');
    return new UserDefinedForm_Controller($get); 
}
```

My problem is that I have created two forms, one is for contacts and one is for booking test drive. Both forms are `UserDefinedForm`s, so if I write another function in `HomePage.php` example:

```
function ShowTestDriveForm(){
    $get = DataObject::get_one('UserDefinedForm');
    return new UserDefinedForm_Controller($get); 
}
```

it will do nothing, or will render my first contacts form.

If I have created two `UserDefinedForm`s what should the php for test drive form look like?

I tried to get it by URLSegment, but it gives me an internal server error:

```
public function showTestDriveForm() {
    $record = DataObject::get_one("UserDefinedForm", "URLSegment = 'BookTestDrive'");
    $results = new UserDefinedForm_Controller($record);

    return $results;
}
```

How do I get the second `UserDefinedForm` to the homepage template?

Answer (score 1):

You have a general misunderstanding on DataObjects, Pages & Controllers.

UserDefinedForm *page* type holds a form construction. They are pages, not separate objects (one does not query forms directly). The controller is the part that handles a request and contains an actual form handler.

You have also not specified a version, so I will assume SilverStripe v3.1

The basic thing you're looking for is:

```
public function ContactForm() {
    return ModelAsController::controller_for($this->ContactPage())->Form();
}
public function TestDriveForm() {
    return ModelAsController::controller_for($this->TestDrivePage())->Form();
}
```

Possibly with a bit more error checking.

This code also makes the assumption that your homepage has two has_one relations to UserDefinedForm pages named ContactPage and TestDrivePage.

Comment: From looking at the original example... `<% control %>` and `DataObject::get_one` looks more like SS2.4